# WCF Service and Client running on different machine

Tags: wcf, http, service

I am writing a simple WCF client/server application. The service runs as a console application.

It works fine when the client and server are running on the same machine. The endpoint URI is:

```
http://localhost:8000/Myservice/Service
```

However, when I move the client to a different machine and set the endpoint URI of the service to:

```
http://192.168.0.10:8000/Myservice/Service
```

(192.168.0.10) is the IP of  the server machine.

The client does not work any more.

I tried to re-add "Add Service Reference" by giving the above URI in the Visual Studio. But the client no longer be able to detect the service running on the server and extract the proxy from it.

I am wondering if there could be any network related issues? I added the service console application to the firewall exception list but it does not solve the problem.

Can anyone help?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you ping the IP address of the server? Can you telnet on port 8000 on the server?

Answer (score 0):

From the WCF Server, you may want to run the following command in cmd: 'netstat -nao'. There, you will find the line with important information related to your port 8000. Take into account that the associated IP address needs to be 0.0.0.0 or your networking IP Address (192.168.0.X). Localhost or 127.0.0.1 will cause your packets to be routed internally.

From the WCF Client, you may want to try the Wireshark application (www.wireshark.org) for further research on networking issues.

Comment: I didn't see any entry in netstat -nao results that contains port 8000. I did run the command "netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.0.10:8000/MyService/Service user=Kevin" to enable this url.

Comment: Note that netstat must be executed from the WCF Server machine. If you don't see any line with port 8000, then you can run a 'telnet localhost 8000' command from the WCF Server to see if the service is started.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can try.

1) from your client machine make sure that you can ping 192.168.0.10 
2) Also need to make sure that port 8000 on your server machine is open for HTTP communication.